# flutter firestore retrieve different data for different page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want it to show different objects when the cards are pressed on the flutter.
There will be a page transition according to the index of the card, and if the password is B, some values ​​in B will appear.There is an example in the picture where the password value is B. Password value for other objects A. How can I show them on different pages according to password value. The only place I get stuck is how the Firestore code will be.

Firestore.instance.collection("User").snapshots() is it true?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jodv.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a query:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("User").where("password", isEqualTo: "B").snapshots()
```

Comment: If the password value is B, show the transactions on another page and A on another page. this is what I want.

Comment: this query will do that